# pdfbox cannot find symbol

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm using code suggested a while ago by @ASu :

```
package pdf_form_filler;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class pdf_form_filler {
public static void listFields(PDDocument doc) throws Exception {
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();
    List<PDFieldTreeNode> fields = form.getFields();

    for(PDFieldTreeNode field: fields) {
        Object value = field.getValue();
        String name = field.getFullyQualifiedName();
        System.out.print(name);
        System.out.print(" = ");
        System.out.print(value);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("test.pdf");
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
    listFields(doc);
}

}
```

However, i keep getting a cannot find symbol error for PDFieldTreeNode. I have the latest pdfbox (2.0.4) but I cannot find the class in it anyway. I tried using this with PDField instead but then get error for .getValue

Comment: It's `List<PDField> getFields()` so your code can't work. If you get an error for `getValue()` then tell (edit the question) what error it is. If it is a stack trace, then include the stack trace. Also read the javadoc for getFields(), it only delivers the root level fields. `getFieldIterator()` may be what you want. Please do also link to the code by "ASu" so that it may be corrected.

Comment: The code by @ASu is exactly the same as I posted but if you want to see it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27795227/4480374 also, this is the first time I'm ever using pdfbox so I don't really understand how to use it. I was just looking for something quick and easy to get form data from pdf

Answer (score 0):

To get all terminal fields, do this:

```
Iterator<PDField> fieldIterator = catalog.getAcroForm();
while (fieldIterator.hasNext())
{
    PDField pdField = fieldIterator.next();
    // do stuff with the field
}
```

`form.getFields()` only gets the top level fields, including nonterminal fields (i.e. fields with no value but children).

A more advanced example can be found in the [PrintFields.java example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/PrintFields.java?view=markup).

Comment: It will return all terminal fields. Including those set readonly, or checkboxes, or radio buttons. To get specific field types you'd need to use `instanceof`. The best would be that you try.